# Using a Dedicated Class & Constructor to initialize Stored Procedure for SQL Transaction via asp.net C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, constructor, webforms, asp.net-4.0

I will try to be as Concise as I can be, **please**.. bear with me, as it should be very simple ...

- **the goal:**

  **trying to universalize** a specific section of a project, that is dealing with the `SQL databse transactions` .

*a side note*

to **assist you** with your answer, I've pasted the folowing (just for Reference)

a Usage-Code : `GetTestOfTablTime()` returns a `DataTable`

class : `SQLDBInteraction` this is another Class - responsible for the final(SQL transaction) stage

in this code below I am constructing what I Call: "*Stored Procedure's Meta Data*"

that class is the one that holds all of the SQL Db SPs :

`HTSPs` (HT is the  company's aliases)

this class is holding **each** `SP` <sub>**(requierd)**</sub> `parameter`s

<sub>`HTSPs` class contains another sub Class, for all `SP`s Names, it only has `const string`s For Each `SP` name</sub>

```C#
public sealed class HTSPs
{

//so for example this is one of the members of this class - a stored procedure
//its mission: get evnents with specified id OF specified userId in spec' month, year..

    public sealed class GetTimesWithCustomerNames
    {
        //if I DO need Constructor for its parameters how do I properly format the constructor?
        public GetTimesWithCustomerNames()
        {
            Userid.ParameterName = ParNameUserid;
            Month.ParameterName = ParNameMonth;
            Year.ParameterName = ParNameYear;
            EventId.ParameterName = ParNameReasonid;

        }

        const string ParNameUserId = "@userId",
                     ParNameMonth = "@month",
                     ParNameYear = "@year",
                     ParNameEventId = "@eventId";

        public static SqlParameter Userid = new SqlParameter();
        public static SqlParameter Month = new SqlParameter();
        public static SqlParameter Year = new SqlParameter();
        public static SqlParameter EventId = new SqlParameter();            
    }
}
```

so the issue is:  **how do I initialize the constractor ?**

what is the Proper way to have your simple customised `StoredProcedure` "*MetaData*"

Iv'e currently Completed the implementation of the Method below (apart from that issue...)

### USAGE

this is a method that returns `DataTable` while using the `HTSPs` `class` / `constuctor`

```C#
using SPTime = HT_DBSchema.HTSPs.GetTimesWithCustomerNames;

private DataTable GetTestOfTablTime()
{
    SQLDBInteraction.DataContainer DC_Time = new SQLDBInteraction.DataContainer();

    SQLDBInteraction.SqlParamList parmsTime = new SQLDBInteraction.SqlParamList();
    Dictionary<SqlParameter, int> SqlCmdParDict = new Dictionary<SqlParameter, int>();
    parmsTime.SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    parmsTime.SqlCmd.CommandText = AppDb.MetaSqlSProc.Time.Name;
    parmsTime.SP_Name = AppDb.MetaSqlSProc.Time.Name;
    parmsTime.TableName = AppDb.MetaSqlTable.Time.Name;

    //While folowing implementation Does Work I comented it out to try using the SP Struct
    //ParmsTTime.SP_Params.Add(new SqlParameter(SPTime.ParNameMonth, 9));
    //ParmsTTime.SP_Params.Add(new SqlParameter(SPTime.ParNameReasonid, 1));
    //ParmsTTime.SP_Params.Add(new SqlParameter(SPTime.ParNameYear, 2012));
    //ParmsTTime.SP_Params.Add(new SqlParameter(SPTime.ParNameUserid, 3571));


    //here's where I'm currently stuck, in section below. trying to assign values for the SqlCommand
    parmsTime.SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(SPTime.ParNameMonth, 9);
    parmsTime.SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(SPTime.ParNameYear, 2012);
    parmsTime.SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(SPTime.ParNameReasonid, 1);
    SPTime.Userid.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    SPTime.Userid.SqlValue = 3571;
    return DC_Time.LocalTbl_V3(ParmsTime);
 }
```

**UPDATE**

the last lines of the code above is trying to implement the parmeters assignment ,

thus it will no longer be required to use :

`SQLDBInteraction.SqlParamList.SP_Params` (which is `List<SqlParameter>`)

and instead i would really like to be able to use

`SQLDBInteraction.SqlParamList.SqlCmd.Parameters`

that way as it is already used for most of the requierd steps to interact with the Database,

so this is how i will drop some unnecessery usage of extra variables

while in same time i wanted to assign SqlCmd ( `parmsTime.SqlCmd.Parameters.Add(......)`)

with the Struct - `SPTime` **Real** `SqlParameters`

... **instead of** using the strings that reperesnts their name as it is now

E.g  `parameter.name` - (`SPTime.ParNameMonth, someValue`)

**final stage- sql trasaction**

the `SQLDBInteraction` Class that does the transaction

```C#
public class SQLDBInteraction
{
    public class SqlParamList
    {
        public SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        public List<SqlParameter> SP_Params = new List<SqlParameter>();
        public String SP_Name;
        public string TableName;
        public string SelectCommand;
        ///public SqlCommandType SelectedCmdType;
    }

    public class DataContainer
    {
        public DataTable LocalTbl_V3(SqlParamList Params)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConnection;
            DataTable Usrs = new DataTable(Params.TableName);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter;

            using (sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HTConn"].ConnectionString))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();

                using (Params.SqlCmd.Connection = sqlConnection)
                {
                    using (sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Params.SqlCmd.CommandText, sqlConnection))
                    {
                        if (sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Count > 0 == false)
                        {
                            sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = Params.SqlCmd;
                            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(Usrs);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return Usrs;
        }
```

I will really appreciate it if someone will find what am I doing wrong with the part of the stored procedure's Parameters Assigned to the `SQL Command`

Comment: What you do wrong? Can we start with * Having code to handle Transactions intead of using the Transaction Namespace, * Using dataset, * using sqldataadpater to actually manually write SQL Statements intead of one of the plenthora of automatism mechanisms of various functionality and Speed, * having a mathod like "GetTestOfTablTime" instead of having a LINQ Provider and allowing flexible use of a data model from higher up Levels. The list goes on, sorry. This is plenty of code trying to solve a Problem that is not there to start with. Use the Transaction mechanisms provided.

Comment: @TomTom thanks. TomTom. good `direction`*ing*... and  lots of help I could see with your last comment (: . Having that said ,  **i know** of many ways to approach this (know as , hello hello ) Didn't Really learn how to work with them (`EF`, `Linq To SQL` , `HyberSomthing` )... **yet** , Do I Realy NEED TO ?? , i am trying to keep it as simple it is (take to account that **it's already an Upgrade** From Code That I  Was Using Before (Plain sql Text (injection prone ) ), so i really  would ...like to take it step by step !

Comment: and @TomTom ...also my applications and scale of the company , my skills , the fact that i am not a master Coder As You .. Take this to account, and give your first advice, choose one or two if you can please.

Comment: No, you do not Need to. You also do not NEED to follow the law. Your code is a clumsy maintenance nightmare. it sucks, is  bad, inflexible, and you are producing a lot of Problems "down the road" with "Down the raod" means within the next 90 days already. For any non-Trainee developer in any Team I run or have run this code would be a firing offense. For a Trainee it would be a SEIROUS talk about where he picked up that Approach to waste Company resources. There is NO excuse for that. Scale of the Company? Unless your Job is to make crappy code there is no relevant scale.

Comment: @TomTom it's not in any standart you know (unless you're more than 8 years experience-old developer this is WebForms , Not Mvc4. The Website is IIS6 sql2005 Winserver2003 AND ASP !! (CLASSIC) i am trying to do some touches ( and me also being still fresh Developer(just few month Self Learning) i'd like to implement it my self . any suggestions as to where to start ? a sample code . usage example for where would you start as it is to try atleast fine tuning the project ?? the owners has some issue with upgrade cause if you want `.net4.5` or advanced up-to-date fet', it will be a problem for him

Comment: I Claim more than 10 years experience with .NET starting with a 0.x build before the public beta, you know. And even back then those pattern you do would be on the firing line - at least for a real programmer Job. At that time only the MS world did NOT use OR mappers.

Comment: @TomTom i got the answer , it is saying also somthing in the end as it is for my experience and not for comerciall use , done not while in work ("

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so at last ... this is my own answer to the 'problem'.

as there will always be opportunities to fine-tune ...and polish it even more,

though **I did find**, a way to implement the solution .

for starters :

### Summary

**connecting between a 3 stages proccess -  the data extraction**, as follows:

1'st stage  : assigning the name and id's for the table and its stored procedure
within the struct

2'nd stage :  constructing  the sql parameter collection / `List <SqlParameter>` 
for the final sql command .

the 3'rd stage : by using these `struct`*s* to format / construct the sql command,

will in return, get a `System.Data` `DataTable` as requested, via the sql instructions
in the stored procedure... naturally.

### prepering a background - for code ReUse

these first 2 blocks of code are sotred in two separated files

the first file is for holding  the **sql databse schema**

table names , tables (custom) IDs , Columns names , and stored procedures names and parameters.

```C#
public sealed class HTDB_Tables
{
    // this is the class that will hold all Sql server - tables Names

    public const string TblTime = "tblTime";
}

 // the class for Stored Procedures Paramaters - (for each stored procedure)
public sealed class HTDB_SPs
{
    // for example this is one of the stored procedures
    public sealed class GetTimesWithCustomerNames
    {

        public static List<SqlParameter> SqlParlst(string SlctdUserID, string SlctdMonth, string SlctdYear, string SlctdEventID)
        {
            SqlParameter Userid = new SqlParameter( UserIdParName, SlctdUserID);
            SqlParameter Month = new SqlParameter(MonthParName, SlctdMonth);
            SqlParameter Year = new SqlParameter(YearParName, SlctdYear);
            SqlParameter EventId = new SqlParameter(EventIdarName, SlctdEventId);

            List<SqlParameter> RetSqlParLst  = new List<SqlParameter>();
            retSqlParLst.Add(UserId);
            retSqlParLst.Add(Month);
            retSqlParLst.Add(Year);
            retSqlParLst.Add(EventId);

            return retSqlParLst;
        }



        const string UserIdParName = "@userId",
                     MonthParName = "@month",
                     YearParName = "@year",
                     EventIParName = "@eventId";
  
    }
}

// a numeric value that's used to reference the table
// the id is passed as a parameter to a javascript-Jquery Update function 
// through the textbox control - "textchange event" - attribute,
// as reference to which table to send the updated data .

// then it is proccessed  in code behind  as table id  inside the application 
// via a switch on the parameter sent by Jquery-ajax function


public sealed class HTDB_tblIDs
{
    public const int tblTime = 1;

   //this is only an example , for one of tables 
   //as it requierd that all sql database tables(that i want to work with this project)
   // will be added here too
   // this could be done via using code smith or through few simple 
  // steps you could do it via C# method that will list all your 
  // database tables names etc'
}
```

**the Second file** is a general usage Helper `nameapace`, that stores all Helper classes,

and one of the classes (next  block of code) , is the one that hodls the `struct`s

one for the table and another for the stored procedure,

these two, will be assinged, later in the application's `code behind`.

```
            public class DBMetaDetails
            {
                public struct DbTable
                {
                    public DbTable(string tableName, int tableId): this()
                    {
                        this.Name = tableName;
                        this.ID = tableId;
                    }
                    public string HtmlOutput;
                    public string Name { get; private set; }
                    public int ID { get; private  set; }
                }

                public struct SProc
                {
                    public SProc(string SProcName, int SprocID, List<SqlParameter> CurrSpParList)
                        : this()
                    {
                        this.Name = SProcName;
                        this.ID = SprocID;
                        this.SpParList = CurrSpParList;
                    }
                    public string Name { get; private set; }
                    public int ID { get; private set; }
                    public List<SqlParameter> SpParList { get; private set; }
                }
            }
```

so both of the codes above are in two separated files ...

meaning codes above could be used in every application i need to create,

so it'll be very easy to implement after this initial background work done.

- second part

**implementation in current project.**

the next codes are used in the "current project" code behind `aspx.cs`

the implementation of struct for the `System.Data` `DataTable`

and its `stored procedure`, that will be used / assigned to the `SqlCommand`

```
public sealed class AppDb
{
    public sealed class SqlTableMeta
    {    
      //id -for usage by jquery, name for the DataTable returnd in the next block of code
        public static DbTbl Time = new DbTbl(HTDB_Tables.TblTime, HTtIDs.tblTime);

    }
    public sealed class SqlSProcMeta
    {

        public static SProc Time = new SProc(HTSPs.SP_GetTimesWithCustomerNames,
                                             HTtIDs.SProcTime,
                                             HTSPs.GetTimesWithCustomerNames.SqlParLst("3571", "9", "2012", "1"));
    }

}
```

the final two steps that could have been in one , though what i want to see is

that the project would have the smallest footprint of extra codes needed to get the data

so i guess the second part that is doing the actual interaction with database

should be soon after tests are complete moved to the Helpers section and out of the `code behind` section of every application .

so next are codes that will gather all preperations and data setup into action

```
private DataTable GetDbTable(DbTbl dbTbl, SProc Sprc)
{
    SQLDBInteraction.DataContainer DC_Time = new SQLDBInteraction.DataContainer();

    //ParmsTime- a class instace, for passing a set of required parameters to final stage
    SQLDBInteraction.SqlParamList ParmsTime = new SQLDBInteraction.SqlParamList();
    
    ParmsTime.SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    //using the stored procedure struct:  assigend to Sqlcommand as its CommandText 
    ParmsTime.SqlCmd.CommandText = Sprc.Name;

    //using stored procedure parameters list - allso via a struct above codes
    ParmsTime.SqlCmd.Parameters.AddRange(Sprc.SpParList.ToArray());

    //using DataTable struct to assign the data table a name
    ParmsTime.TableName = dbTbl.Name;

    return DC_Time.LocalTbl_V3(ParmsTime);
}
```

the final stage: sql database interaction

```
public class SQLDBInteraction
{

    public class SqlParamList
    {

        public SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        public List<SqlParameter> SP_Params = new List<SqlParameter>();
        
        public string TableName;
        public string SelectCommand;
        ///public SqlCommandType SelectedCmdType;
    }

    public class DataContainer
    {


        public DataTable LocalTbl_V3(SqlParamList Params)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConnection;
            DataTable retDt = new DataTable(Params.TableName);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter;

            using (sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["useyourwebconfigconnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();

                using (Params.SqlCmd.Connection = sqlConnection)
                {

                    using (sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Params.SqlCmd.CommandText, sqlConnection))
                    {
                        if (sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Count > 0 == false)
                        {
                            sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = Params.SqlCmd;
                            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(retDt);
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
            return retDt;
        }



   }


}
```

this is only a test, yet it works very fast
and very easy to implemet , it will fit perfectly as it is for personal or small buisness use

comments are very welcome ...

thanks